# How to replace one of multiple possible strings followed by zero or more periods

Tags: regex, sed

I try to remove `JR. Jr jr.` with `sed -i "s/(Jr\|JR\|jr)\.*//g"` but it doesn't work. Why and what should I do?

Comment: You are escaping the pipes (regex OR), if you escape them they are just plain strings... so, don't escape them and use `sed -i "s/(Jr|JR|jr)\.*//g"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to backslash parenthesis too, so :

```
sed -i "s/\(Jr\|JR\|jr\)\.*//g"
```

or :

```
sed -i -r 's/(Jr|JR|jr)\.*//g'
```

or even better :

```
sed -i -r 's/jr\.*//ig'
```

Comment: Probably easier to use a character class. i.e `sed -i 's/[Jj][Rr]\.*//g'`

Comment: Found even better solution: `sed -i -r 's/jr\.*//ig'`

Comment: @sputnick solution in comment would replace `jR` that OP does not request.  It may be OK.

Comment: OP have choice now ;)